# find attribute in xml tags with reg exp in python

Tags: python

I am trying to find the attributes in the following tag 'row':

> row Id="11" PostTypeId="1" AcceptedAnswerId="1248" CreationDate="2008-07-31T23:55:37.967" Score="749" ViewCount="75079" Body="<p>Given a specific <code>DateTime</code> value, how do I display relative time, like:</p>
>
> <ul>
> <li>2 hours ago</li>
> <li>3 days ago</li>
> <li>a month ago</li>
> </ul>
>
> <p>Et cetera?</p>
> " OwnerUserId="1" LastEditorUserId="402022" LastEditorDisplayName="Rich B" LastEditDate="2013-12-16T00:28:55.377" LastActivityDate="2014-04-09T11:50:10.300" Title="How do I calculate relative time?" Tags="<datediff>" AnswerCount="31" CommentCount="10" FavoriteCount="428" CommunityOwnedDate="2009-09-04T13:15:59.820"

How could I get the attribute-value pair of ,for example,"ViewCount" using regexp in python?

Comment: bs4 is not the only xml parsing library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use any xml parser, you can simply do it using regex:

```
tagYouWannaLookFor = "ViewCount"
regex = r"\b"+ tagYouWannaLookFor + "=\"(.*?)\""
match = re.search(regex, test_str)
```

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/a7KSbr/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> match.group(1)
>>>
75079
```

Sample python [code](https://repl.it/NY8M/0)

Comment: Thanks, that's really help!

Comment: Parsing an XML with a regex is simply wrong and should be frowned upon

Comment: I've already mentioned that in the answer, but that was OP's requirement and as per the requirement this is a possible approach, also this is not parsing. parsing would be a bad idea, if you just want one value. Why parse a long xml, just for a single value? This is just a possible use case OP might have some other scenario.

Comment: also, the question asks for a solution using regex and I guess this answer does the same. @DeepSpace

Comment: @ZhetaoZhuang 1. So the question is wrong on its own.  2. The question is about Python, why did you answer in PHP?

Comment: @DeepSpace I misinterpreted it as a php question, updated thanks. and you can't say the question is wrong OP was just looking for an alternative without xml parsing, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @AshishRanjan You can keep writing it's not and I can keep writing that it is. It will not change the fact that XML is **nonregular** and should not be parsed with ***regular** expression*

Comment: @DeepSpace yeah that's correct, there're numerous questions on that. This was a different question though.